# Include order for microtype and cleveref is important (only) in LuaLaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, luatex, cleveref, microtype

When using a `\label` inside an `align` environment of the `amsmath` package and also importing `cleveref` and `microtype` you get an error for the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{eq1}
    1 < 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Running it yields this error:

```
$ lualatex test.tex
[...]
! Use of \label doesn't match its definition.
<argument>  \label {
         eq1} 1 < 2 
l.10 \end{align}
```

This seems to only be an issue with LuaLaTeX. It works fine with both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.
Additionally it works with `\begin{equation}` but not with align.

Comment: Interestingly the error occurs in `align` only, not in `equation`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I checked that, too, but didn't put in the question. I'll add this bit just to be more precise.

Comment: The conflict is with `luatexbase` (loaded by `microtype`), whose definition of `\@gobble@optarg` differs from that of `cleveref`. (@DavidCarlisle, @JosephWright?)

Comment: This issue is not only with `microtype`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351862/load-pgfplots-after-cleveref-throws-error-with-lualatex

Answer (score 3):

After trying out the answer is that `cleveref` should be loaded **after** `microtype`. So changing the example to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{eq1}
    1 < 2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

works fine.

**EDIT:**
It seems that the issue really seems to be the combination of the three packages, because there are different orders (also one in which `cleveref` is included *before* `microtype`) which work.

- `amsmath` → `cleveref` → `microtype`: Does **NOT** work
- `amsmath` → `microtype` → `cleveref`: *Works*
- `cleveref` → `amsmath` → `microtype`: *Works*
- `cleveref` → `microtype` → `amsmath`: *Works*
- `microtype` → `amsmath` → `cleveref`: *Works*
- `microtype` → `cleveref` → `amsmath`: *Works*

**Conclusion:** All *but* one loading order works fine and I was „lucky“ to use exactly this.

Comment: `cleveref` should be loaded last in almost any case, even **after** `hyperref`

Comment: Also in your answer, `cleveref` is loaded *first*, which is most probably a typo?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the comment. I just noticed it that it states so in the documentation. I must have missed this bit by now… Shame on me.

Comment: @Troy This was an accident, but it still works this way. I'll have a look and update my answer accordingly.