# Load pgfplots after cleveref throws error with lualatex

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, labels, cleveref

I would like to load `pgfplots` after `cleveref` due to modularise my preamble. But when loading the packages in this order I get the following error:

`Use of \label doesn't match its definiton. \end{align}`

I use TeXlive 2016 with `lualatex`, because I use system fonts in my origin preamble.
Here is my MWE (compiles correct with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{eqnEinstein}
    E &= mc^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351383/include-order-for-microtype-and-cleveref-is-important-only-in-lualatex

Comment: The source of the problem is a clash between the package luatexbase and cleveref. Both define \@gobble@optarg but with different meaning. As a work around load pgfplots after cleveref.

Comment: Sorry I didn't seen that you don't want to load before cleveref. But until the problem has been resolved you will have to do it. Also be aware that cleveref should be loaded very late in a document, even after hyperref.

Comment: Thanks David and Ulrike.
Hopefully the problem will be resolved in near future.
I know the issues with varioref, hyperref, and cleveref and load them in the correct order late in my documents.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/151/

Comment: The above bug is now marked as fixed at source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating PGFPlots to v1.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clash is with `luatexbase` as Ulrike comented, but `luatexbase` shouldn't be needed on any latex release from 2015 on, and as far as I can see it isn't needed here so if you just suppress that package the document works without error.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@luatexbase.sty\endcsname{}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \label{eqnEinstein}
    E &= mc^2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```