# Use of \label doesn't match its definition. with package luatodonotes

Tags: errors, todonotes

When compiling following document, I get the error message `Use of \label doesn't match its definition`

```
%! TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{luatodonotes} % can be resolved by using todnotes
% \usepackage{todonotes}   

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   a&= b & c &= d
  \label{eq:elastic_moduli_relations}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I was trying to track down the error source. However, I do not see any re-definition of \label in the github repository https://github.com/fabianlipp/luatodonotes.

Can one show me what luatodonotes does which is responsible for this error message?

Comment: Load the package before cleveref. `cleveref` is a package that should be loaded very late as it wants to redefine a lot of commands.

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand it completely, but I am glad it works now.

Comment: It is this incompability between luatexbase and cleveref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351862/load-pgfplots-after-cleveref-throws-error-with-lualatex/351882#351882. luatodonotes shouldn't load luatexbase, so you should inform the author.

Comment: Just since this is the post that pulls up when I searched for my error: `Use of \@@cref@getlabel doesn't match its definition.` and "Runaway argument?" and for better visibility, compiling on Overleaf in "Fast [Draft]" was resulting in this issue, which is possibly related to `\zexternaldocument` since commenting out that line was the difference between a PDF being produced or not (same errors show up either way though)